# Java: waitfor() grandchild process in windows

Tags: java, windows, subprocess

Is there any way to wait for not only the process I spawned but also for its children if there's any?

Example: my java process A spawns process B (process B not coded by me) and B just launches process C and closes. Can I make my process A wait also for C?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're using Java 9+ you can try [`ProcessHandle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html). Specifically the `children()`/`descendants()` and `onExit()` methods.

Comment: @Slaw that looks like an answer with just a little bit more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Java 9+ you can use the [`java.lang.ProcessHandle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html) interface. This interface has two methods, `children()` and `descendants()`, which both return `Stream<ProcessHandle>`. The difference being `children()` only returns *direct* descendants whereas `descendants()` returns *all* descendants. Some of the methods of `ProcessHandle` are present in `java.lang.Process` as well but you can obtain a `ProcessHandle` by calling `Process.toHandle()`.

You would then use the [`onExit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html#onExit()) method which returns a [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) you can wait on (and optionally add behavior for when the process exits).

Here's an example where `Main` launches `Child` which in turn launches `GrandChild`.

**Main.java**

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Process proc = new ProcessBuilder("java", "Child").inheritIO().start();
        proc.onExit().join();
        proc.descendants().map(ProcessHandle::onExit).forEach(CompletableFuture::join);
        System.out.println("Main exiting");
    }
}
```

**Child.java**

```
public class Child {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new ProcessBuilder("java", "GrandChild").inheritIO().start();
        System.out.println("Child exiting...");
    }

}
```

**GrandChild.java**

```
public class GrandChild {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("GrandChild sleeping...");
        Thread.sleep(5_000L); // 5 seconds
        System.out.println("GrandChild exiting...");
    }

}
```

The `GrandChild` class sleeps for 5 seconds to simulate work. The `Child` class simply launches `GrandChid` and then exits to simulate a process that launches a longer running process.

In `Main` I call `proc.onExit().join()` before waiting on each descendant to allow the `Child` process time to actually launch its own child process (`GrandChild`).

Due to the asynchronicity involved in launching separate processes I can't guarantee that `descendants()` will cover all the processes you expect to be launched. For instance, this gets much more complicated if each child process can arbitrarily spawn their own child processes. Both `descendants()` and `children()` return *snapshots* which means a child process might get launched *after* you call one of the two methods.

---

If you control the code for all the descendant processes it might be easier to have each child process wait for all their children to exit before exiting themselves. An example if each process is a Java program:

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new ProcessBuilder("java", "Child").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
        System.out.println("Main exiting");
    }
}
```

**Child.java**

```
public class Child {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new ProcessBuilder("java", "GrandChild").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
        System.out.println("Child exiting...");
    }

}
```

**GrandChild.java**

```
public class GrandChild {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("GrandChild sleeping...");
        Thread.sleep(5_000L); // 5 seconds
        System.out.println("GrandChild exiting...");
    }

}
```

Here each process waits for its child process to exit via [`Process.waitFor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor()). This has the bonus of also working on Java 8 and below (`waitFor()` has existed since 1.0). Since each process waits for their children to exit the first ancestor will only exit once *all* descendant processes have exited.

The concept here is the same as in the first example except the logic is handled by each process individually rather than all in the "master" process.

Comment: Thanks, works as a charm. Just to make it clear, wouldn't the `proc.onExit().join();` in `Main` do the same thing as a more straightforward `proc.waitFor();` ?

Comment: @akpla There are differences. The method `onExit().join()` doesn't throw checked exceptions. However, this returns a `ProcessHandle` which doesn't seem to allow you to obtain the exit code of the process. Another, important, thing about `CompletableFuture.join()` is that **it does not support interruption**.

Comment: @akpla However, if checked exceptions aren't an issue for you then feel free to use `waitFor()`.