# Can't kill a process created by ProcessBuilder

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, process

I'm just trying to kill a process created by ProcessBuilder and all its children. This is what I've done until now:

1. Create the process:

```
            File workdir = new File( this.midiasFolder );
            String[] cmmm = {"./urlworker.sh", this.url, this.streamName};
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmmm);
            pb.directory(workdir);
            this.process = pb.start();
```

Note I store the process in a global variable `this.process` and the process "alias" (streamName)

2. Desperately try to kill it:

```
    public void stopWorker() {
        this.process.destroy();
        this.killByPid();
        this.process.destroyForcibly();     
    }

    private void killByPid() {
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps aux | grep -i " + this.streamName + " | grep -v grep | awk {'print $1'} | xargs kill -9");
            p.waitFor();
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            logger.error( e.getMessage() );
        }
    }
```

Some notes:

I can't just kill all `ffmpeg` because may be others running not spawned by me. Can't kill by `urlworker.sh` for same reason. It must be killed by alias.

Also tried `xargs pkill -P` instead `xargs kill -9` but have no effect.

When I run only `pkill -P <PID_OF_URLWORKER_SH>` directly in console I get was I need (everyone is killed - urlworker.sh AND ffmpeg spawned by it).

... but ...

`ps aux | grep -i <ALIAS> | grep -v grep | awk {'print $1'} | xargs kill -9`

... have no effect. No one is killed.

By the way "alias" is passed as parameter to urlworker.sh even it is actually not used in ffmpeg. Just to keep the reference to the script process. So this is the result of a classical `ps aux` of my problem (from inside the Docker):

```
    1 root      1:33 java -jar /opt/lib/midiapublisher-1.0.war
  133 root      0:00 sh
  301 root      0:00 {urlworker.sh} /bin/sh ./urlworker.sh rtsp://<ADDRESS>/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=2 alias
  303 root      0:00 ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel panic -i rtsp://<ADDRESS>/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=2 -rtsp_transport tcp -pix_fmt yuv42
  344 root      0:00 ps aux
```

This work (kill both 301 and 303):

`pkill -P 301`

This NOT work (no one is killed):

`ps aux | grep -i alias | grep -v grep | awk {'print $1'} | xargs pkill -P`

How can I kill the procces I started and all process that this procces spawn using an alias as reference?

Comment: Maybe you should start with explaining why you think that you need `process.destroy();`, `killByPid();`, *and* `process.destroyForcibly();`.

Comment: Runtime.exec does not invoke a shell, so `|` is not recognized as a special character.  You could prepend `bash -c` to the command, but I would first try `ProcessHandle.allProcesses().filter(p -> p.info().commandLine().filter(c -> c.contains("alias")).isPresent()).destroyForcibly()`.

Comment: @VGR please read the last part of my question. Even typing directly into console the ```grep``` stuff is not working ( appart java )

Comment: I made a mistake rejecting the edition. Sorry. The ```awk``` tag is better than ```java```.

Comment: I think we could remove the Java part. It is just to show the entire process. When I try to run urlworker.sh using the console I have the same result failing to kill the process. Maybe the problem relies in that that compound command... don't know.

Comment: @Holger I think I must try everything that can help me to kill the process. Once I have the correct method all things that is not useful or related to the problem will be removed. Until now I'm blind shooting everywhere. None of them is working anyway.

Comment: @VGR I can give a try in your pure java solution ... but I remember one of my old try kill only the process that spawn the script and leave it child alive .... worth trying.

Comment: It’s important to understand the actual goal, to avoid wasting efforts discussing the attempted solutions when there’s a straight-forward solution for the actual goal. Killing all sub-processes can be done like `process.descendants().forEach(ProcessHandle::destroy);`

Comment: @Holger you rule! It worked! And thanks for the advice. I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: Any difference between ```process.descendants()``` and ```process.children()``` ??

Comment: This is a good reading although the question is slightly different. Found it after learn about ```process.decendants()```.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51644218/java-waitfor-grandchild-process-in-windows. In fact @Holger showed me that it is worth consulting the code completion sometimes... ;-)

Comment: Or [the official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html#descendants())…